# Listview item compare

Tags: vb.net

I've tried everything I know and couldn't make it work.

If a listview.item(1) item.text has the same listview.item(0) item.text can I count them and make it 2xItem.text?

example:

listview

coke
coke
7up

2x coke
1x 7up

Comment: Why are you adding two items with the same `Text` in the first place?

Comment: It's a cash register application, i add the item that the client asks for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) to help. Create a dictionary of string and int then update and insert accordingly.

```
Dim itemDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
    'Loop through all item in ListView
    Dim previousValue As Integer
    If (itemDictionary.TryGetValue(item.Text, previousValue)) Then
        'If can get value add 1 to the previous value
        itemDictionary(item.Text) = previousValue + 1
    Else
        'If cant get value = not found, then add new
        itemDictionary.Add(item.Text, 1)
    End If
Next
```

To access the value from dictionary, simply use the Value and Key

```
For Each item In itemDictionary
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}x {1}", item.Value, item.Key))
Next
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the price aswell?

Comment: You can use [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. So you can add any number of column you need. [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable) might help. Or you can just multiple up your quantity with unit price?